# How many words are in each sentence of the file based in this code Java

Tags: java, file

I need to count how many words are in each sentence of the file based in this code
We have the file called archivo:

```
File archivo = null;
try {

     archivo = new File("Text.txt");
     String line;
     FileReader fr = new FileReader (archivo);
     BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

     int i,a=0;

     while((linea=br.readLine())!=null) {

         for(i=0;i<line.length();i++){

             if(i==0){

                 if(line.charAt(i)!=' ')

                     a++;
             }else{

                 if(line.charAt(i-1)==' ')
                    if(line.charAt(i)!=' ')     
                        a++;

             }  
         }
     }
```

Here we print the number of words, but i also need the number of words per sentence

```
     System.out.println("There are "+a+" words");

     fr.close();

     }catch(IOException a){

     System.out.println(a);

     }
    }
}
```

The text.txt says:

hi
I'm Katie
and I have two cats.

Comment: And what's the output?

Comment: It has to be the number of words per sentence, like "We have 5 words in the line 1, 2 in the line 2,..."

Comment: you're saying number of words in sentence them you're saying number of words in line, a line is not equal to a sentence

Comment: Did you forget to mention something important like "Every line will contain exactly one sentence"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it as follows:

```
String line;
int count=0, totalCount=0;
while((line=br.readLine())!=null) {
    count = line.split("\\s+").length;
    System.out.println("The number of words in '" + line + "' is: " + count);
    totalCount += count;
}
System.out.println("The total number of words in the file is " + count);
```

**Explanation:** [String::split](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) function splits a string into an array of strings based on the specified regex. The regex, `\\s+` means one or more spaces. For each line, the program is printing `count` i.e. the number of words (which is the length of the resulting array after the split happens) and also adding it to `totalCount`. In the end, the program prints `totalCount` (which is the total number of words in the file).